# feeding tensorflow data into placeholder Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting an error while I am feeding data into a placeholder
code gist is [kmeans.py](https://gist.github.com/evalsocket/6bad038afd754ea09dbff558d04199eb)

The error is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [200,2]
[[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[200,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Are you able to inspect x to check that it is definitely the correct type. At first glance it looks ok. What happens if you don't fetch points (as it's already x so why fetch it back?)

Comment: I try same thing but i get same shape and same datatype for x and points

Answer (score 1):

The one that is fed into placeholder should not be a tensorflow tensor.
For example, if the data type of x in following line is one tensor,

```
sess.run(some_fetches, feed_dict={input: x})
```

Then it will failed to run. This one will be ok,

```
sess.run(some_fetches, feed_dict={input: sess.run(x)})
```

So ugly!